# redirect to created posts with vue and mongo

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, vue.js, axios

How could I redirect the user to post which he created? I'm using mongo, express, and vue
My `POST` request looks like this:

```
async addOrder () {
      if(this.name.length > 0 && this.address.length > 4 && this.city.length > 3) {
      await PostsService.addOrder(
        this.postData = {
        order: this.cart,
        name: this.name,
        address: this.address,
        city: this.city,
        zip: this.zip,
        country: this.countries,
        summary: this.summary,
        status: this.status,
      })
      this.$router.push({ name: 'EachOrder', params: { id: order.id} )
        } else {
          alert('Fill the form')
        }
      },
```

I knew, that I need somehow get created `ID`, but I don't have access before this post request. Any idea :D?

(Sorry for my English ^^)

Comment: `PostsService.addOrder` should return the `ID`? You can capture the `ID` there and then navigate.

Comment: No, It can't :/ But I figure it out how to do that :D Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

```
async addOrder () {
  if(this.name.length > 0 && this.address.length > 4 && this.city.length > 3) {
  await PostsService.addOrder(
    this.postData = {
    order: this.cart,
    name: this.name,
    address: this.address,
    city: this.city,
    zip: this.zip,
    country: this.countries,
    summary: this.summary,
    status: this.status,
    randomNum: this.getRandomNum()
  })
  setTimeout(() => {
    this.$router.push({name: 'EachOrder', params: { id: this._id} })  
  }, 3000);

    } else {
      alert('Fill the form')
    }
  },
  getRandomNum() {
   return this.randomNum = Math.random() * 30
  },
  async getId() {
    const response = await PostsService.getOrder()
    const mapdata = response.data.map(item => {
      if (item.randomNum === this.randomNum) {
      this._id =  item._id
      }
      console.log(this._id)
    })
  }
```

But maybe someone know how to make it easier cuz it's a lot of code

Comment: You can do away with the whole "randomNum" business by creating a post ID on the backend (Express). You would include the post ID in the response that your backend returns. Then, on the front-end (Vue) you just make a POST request to your PostsService, and wait for the response. When the response comes back, you extract the post ID and use that to redirect the user.

Comment: Thanks :D now its better